# CSS border breaking

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am composing notifications that consist of a title and some description. And displaying it next to the form.

Composing elements in jQuery:

```
var $title = $('<span></span>').addClass('title').text($('#title').val());
var $description = $('<span></span>').addClass('description').text(plainText);
var $notification = $('<span></span>').append($title).append($description).addClass('notification');
```

CSS:

```
.notification{
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Ideally, I would like the border to surround the title and description. What am I doing wrong here?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7b3j2/18/)

Comment: Add `display: inline-block;` to `.notification { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add display:block; to .notification calss

```
.notification{
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 10px;
    display: block;
}
```

or change the notification wrapper to div instead span

```
var $notification = $('<div></div>').append($title).append($description).addClass('notification');
```

Demo: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7b3j2/18/)

Comment: I liked your idea of using `<div>` instead.

Answer (score 3):

`<span>` is an inline element by default. To force it to respect the rectangular dimensions of the content inside, use `display: inline-block;`

```
.notification{
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/7b3j2/20/